# Deploy a newer version of VBA activex dll in client server

Tags: vb6, com+, regsvr32

I did some edits to a class of a an activex dll project in VB6 IDE, made a newer dll by clicking on « make dll » a newer dll had been generated.

Copied the dll and tried to register it by calling regsvr32 in client server. the registration had been completed : i checked the registry keys and newer keys has been generate for my object.

When i start the website i have an error in the first class called ( which i didnt edit at all )

Actually, those dlls are installed as an application com+ so they can be called from classic asp pages. However, simply registering my new dll with regsvr32 does not make it work.

By the way, when i put back the older dll, everythings Ok

Any idea how to update this com object and why registering the dll does not work?

Comment: Did you maintain [binary compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15771401/11683) with the original version?

Comment: Besides the abovbe mentioned binary compatibility, have you made sure to register the DLL with the 32-bit version of RegSvr32, located in SysWOW64?